# SQL: Является ли одно множество подмножеством другого (пересечение множеств)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть два множества (набора): `(641,16,21)` и `(12,66,641,78,16,22,21,15)`.

Нужно SQL запросом проверить, что первое множество полностью входит во второе, т.е. является его подмножеством.

Есть ли в SQL какие-либо конструкции, способные решить эту задачу??

---

*UPD: 2019-07-08:*

Необходимо решение для СУБД MariaDB <10.2 или MySQL <8.

Comment: А множества динамические?

Comment: @radar4ick , да, конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел статью «[Пересечение множеств в MySQL](http://audio.probudget.ru/programmirovanie/peresecheniem-mnozhestv-v-mysql)» в ней пример, как реализовать подобное пересечение.

Немного адаптированный под мою задачу код из статьи:

```
SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `filter_product`
WHERE `active` = 1 AND `option_id` IN (641,16,21)
GROUP BY `product_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `option_id`) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял это не данные из таблиц. Тогда

```
with A(id) as (values (641),(16),(21)), B(id) as (values (12),(66),(641),(78),(16),(22),(21),(15))
select id from a where id not in (select id from B)
```

В ответе получите список элементов A, не имеющихся в B. Если он пуст, значит это подмножество. К случаю, если данные все же берутся из бд, думаю, адаптируете сами

Comment: Как я понимаю, CTE реализовано в MySQL 8 и MariaDB 10.2. А как получить пересечение множеств в MariaDB 10.1 или MySQL <8??

Comment: Учитывая, что это не целевое использование бд, посмею предположить, что никак. Только записывая данные в таблицы

Comment: Странно, с учетом того, что множества (наборы) присутствуют в СУБД как тип данных (SET), не реализованы основные функции теории множеств...

Comment: Они очень даже реализованы. Не реализована возможность их применять к данным, не внесенным в саму бд